# Can someone tell me how a service works in angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, service, angular-components

I ' m a beginner on Angular and I'm currently working on a mastermind game on Angular 8.I made a service which contains the number of tries(type:number) left and 2 components: the first one receives the number of tries from the service and display it without any event,the second one can change its value after some events.My problem is that when the number of tries changes in the service,the number of tries which the first component receives from the service and  displays doesn 't change.But when i change  the type of the number of tries from a number to an array(an array of length equals to 1)in the service,the first component displays the right number of tries left which the second component have changed.My question is why it worked with an array but not with numbers?

Comment: It will easier to help if you can include some code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need more information (the code), to explain your scenario. However if you want a variable declared in your service to have the same value everywhere in your application, you need to define this variable as "STATIC".